# user in database are not login after restoring the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

When i restored database from one server to other server the user's are not login in database but its shown in database then i delete it and make it again through sql/server/security/login and then its work. is someone tell me how can i restore database and do not define user every time...

Comment: Could you be clearer on what you mean by users in database. Are these end users whose login credentials are stored in your own tables? Are you talking about database admins/users? What do you mean by define user?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps: [How to move databases between computers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546). Especially *Step 2: How to transfer logins and password*s.

Comment: Might also be step 3, orphaned users

Answer (score 1):

Assuming logins exist, you have the "orphaned users" situation

Either use [`sp_change_users_login`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) or [`ALTER USER ... WITH LOGIN ..`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) for SQL Server 2005 +